# Is there a pattern for ず negatives?

Tags: conjugations, pitch-accent

I'm thinking of a particular word, 足らず, which I have audio of here, https://no.forvo.com/word/%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A/#ja

I'm thinking it's 足らず{HLL}. Is there a pattern to how the pitches of ず negative verbs are, or must they simply be remembered?

Comment: She is saying [たらず]【HLL】 but it’s not the correct accent when 足らず doesn’t follow another word like 舌.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pattern for 〜ず verbs, which is that they normally follow the accent of the base verb:

**Accented base → Accent on mora before ず

Heiban base → Heiban**

- できる{LHL}→できず{LHL}
- はなす{LHL}→はなさず{LHHL}
- きく{LH}→きかず{LHH}
- いう{LH}→いわず{LHH}
- ...the majority of verbs follow this pattern

---

However, there are some exceptions:

- おもわず{LHLL} is the traditional accent as a standalone adverb (and is still most common but おもわず{LHHL} is also heard), while おもわず{LHHL} is more common when it's the full verb, IMO
- あらず{HLL}
- おらず{HLL} (おらず{LHL} is also heard)
- たえず{HLL}
- とわず{HLL} (とわず{LHL} is also heard)
- ならず{HLL}
- べからず{LHLL}
- You occasionally hear のこらず{LHLL}, but のこらず{LHHL} is more common these days
- いわずとも{LHLL} (as opposed to heiban -- only when used with とも)

As for why these exist, I believe that having the accent *two* mora before ず is the traditional accent for this conjugation, and as a result you can still see it fossilized in certain adverbs and other words that feel like they have a distinct meaning (i.e., distinct entry in the speakers lexicon) beyond just a generic ~ず conjugation. But occasionally speakers may choose to just say the more regular/modern "one mora before ず" accent even for these lexicalized items.

---

Then, there are cases where a 〜ず-inflected verb compounds with a noun and as as a result gets a compound noun accent:

- はじしらず{LHHLL}
- いのちしらず {LHHHLL}
- おやしらず {LHHLL}
- やくたたず{LHHLL}

But there are cases where you might think it should get such a noun compound accent but doesn't (i.e. is not thought of as noun compounding):

- むこうみず{LHLLL}
- われしらず{HLLLL}

In the case of 足らず, as a normal conjugation it would be たらず{LHH} (e.g., 恐るるに足らず), but this is often commonly seen in noun compounds like したたらず{LHHLL}, じたらず{LHLL}, すんたらず{HHHLL}, [amount]たらず{HLL}.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I lack the reputation to post this as a comment to the other answer, so I guess I'll make my own.

According to section 89 in the 新明解日本語アクセント辞典　rule appendix, on accented verbs the standard rule is to keep the accent in place rather than moving it to be before the ず. For example, はなさず would be はな\さず rather than はなさ\ず as suggested by Darius.

Other examples given by the shinmeikai include:

読まず　＝　よ\まず

飲まず　＝　の\まず

食わず　＝　く\わず

思わず　＝　おも\わず

And according to random stuff I could find online, some people will also read it with the pattern shifted like how Darius said, but the above is whats considered technically correct and more widespread generally speaking afaik.

Comment: The accents you list are defunct, almost no one uses them anymore, even announcers and other voice professionals, etc. (Except for the exceptions I listed where they have been fossilized.) Please check Youglish (use the blue arrow button to go to the next hit): [話さず](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%95%E3%81%9A/japanese?) [読まず](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9A/japanese) [飲まず](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E9%A3%B2%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9A/japanese?) [食わず](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E9%A3%9F%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9A/japanese?) (思わず was addressed in my answer).

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for the link too, that seems like a useful website.